# How to generate training data in XOR gate based on Neural Network

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, xor

how to modify it to achieve simpler logical AND  and logical OR（linear)? How to generate training data in the XOR project? Why is this kind of data called toy data?

Comment: `x=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]` and `y=[[0],[1],[1],[0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

That means play with data like small toy/ Well, try to include in the above of your code a TOY library, and here you go you'll get a toy structure